# Confused between bandwidth and frequency

Tags: computer-networks

I am new to Computer Science and started learning about computer networking very recently. I know that *bandwidth* means how many bits can be sent through the channel in 1 second. However, recently I came across another definition of bandwidth which says it is the range of frequency where the signal is received.

How to think intuitively of this? *Frequency* is the number of cycles per second. **What is the relation between frequency and bandwidth?**

Please note that I am a lay man. Kindly elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bandwidth" has several different meanings. Among others, it can refer to either a frequency range or to data rate in bits/second. You have to use the context to figure out which is meant.

These two notions of bandwidth are not directly related, but a signal with a wider frequency range (i.e., higher signal bandwidth) can usually transmit data at a higher rate (i.e., has higher data bandwidth). However, [the relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem) also depends on how much noise is present.

Comment: thank you sir. But say in TV network, each channel is having 1 frequency range. Then when signal is sent(set of different frequency ranges), how in TV signal is declassified according to frequency range.